# OBSOLETE - StackBook - let your Online Community friends know what you're doing on Stack Overflow

Tags: app, obsolete, facebook

### About

StackBook helps mashup service for you let your Online Community (right now only Facebook) friends know what you're doing on Stack Overflow.

### License

MSPL

### Access

http://stackbook.mourfield.com/

### Beta

StackBook is in beta stage. Please help us by trying it out and letting us know what you think. Please post any and all feature requests/bug reports/criticisms either here or on our Feedback (User Voice) link on the StackBook site.

### Code

http://stackbook.codeplex.com

### Platform

Web Application

### Contact

[Peter Mourfield](https://stackapps.com/users/424/peter-mourfield) or via the User Voice link on the StackBook site

*6/15/2010* - I found a problem in the API calls that I'm using. So I'm taking the app down until I can resolve the problem. Sorry for any inconvenience. See [Problem getting a users questions within a date range](https://stackapps.com/questions/768/) for more information.

*6/19/2010* - The API problem has been fixed and the application is back online.
*UPDATE*: Had to take the application back offline because of this issue [Problem getting a users answers within a date range](https://stackapps.com/questions/797/problem-getting-a-users-answers-within-a-date-range).

*6/20/2010* - Looks like everything is up and running!

Comment: So the app is down ever since 2010.. :(

Comment: Access and Code links are not working. The user was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It would also be nice to have the ability to track questions and answers from other SO sites ( like ServerFault)

Answer (score 1):

Great idea. I'm more interested in Twitter updates than facebook. Family and friends tend to follow me on facebook and aren't interested in what I get up to as a programmer. On the other hand, all my geek friends and colleagues follow me on twitter. Strange, that.