# Problem getting a users questions within a date range

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, users

I'm having a problem returning a list of users questions within a given timespan. I understand that the documentation ( http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users/{id}/questions ) that fromDate and toDate parameters are filtering on the creation_date parameter, but when I make the following call:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/66716/questions/?key={MyApiKey}&fromdate=1276770201&todate=1276770437&sort=activity&order=desc&type=jsontext

I'm getting items back that are before my fromdate, such as "creation_date": 1257388234

Anyone have any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, this is a bug.  Will update when fixed.

Comment: I know I'm splitting hairs, but with `sort=activity` you should be looking at the `last_activity_date`.  It's out of range too, so this is a real bug.  I just wasn't sure if you were aware of this and you simply copy/pasted the wrong field from the results.

Comment: @Bill, Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. By my read, the docs imply that the sort field is for the order of the records, not which field the method filters on. May need to update the docs too.

Comment: I think I was the one reading the doc wrong.  It's min and max that take sort into account, not fromdate and todate.  Please disregard my comment above.

Comment: @Bill, no worries. Also, it looks like this bug is fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed now.