# Problem getting a users answers within a date range

Tags: bug, status-completed, users, answers

This issue is similar to [Problem getting a users questions within a date range](https://stackapps.com/questions/768/problem-getting-a-users-questions-within-a-date-range). Only this time I'm calling a different api and getting unexpected results.

I'm calling
[http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/66716/answers/?key={MyApiKey}&sort=activity&order=desc&fromdate=1276770201&type=jsontext](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/66716/answers/?key=%7BMyApiKey%7D&sort=activity&order=desc&fromdate=1276770201&type=jsontext) . I'm expecting to get all questions answered by this user after the from date, but I'm getting all of the users answers.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

(Its kind of safe to assume these are bugs by the way, we are in beta)

Comment: The site may be in beta, but we can make mistakes too :) Fixed your typo.

Comment: @George - I'm just trying to say, we're aware that we make mistakes and its *ok* to suggest we've got some floating out there in the API.  We won't get mad, promise!